# C++ SFML функция waitEvent вызывает белое окно

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sfml, c11

Проблема такая: функция Window.waitEvent() в библиотеке SFML вызывает белое окно. То есть ожидает каких-то событий от пользователя. При срабатывании события окно меняет свой цвет на чёрный.
Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при старте программы окно не висело белым цветом в ожидании события, а сразу становилось чёрным.
Может можно как-то задать какое-нибудь единичное событие при старте? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было перед waitEvent вызвать window.display(). Тему можно закрывать.